# Display all the accounts name as a dropdown in the lightning component during component initialization

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display all the account names in the dropdown in the lightning component during component initialization. Below is the code.

```
<aura:component controller="AccountList">
<aura:attribute name="Accounts" type="Account[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}" />
<h2 class="slds-page-header__title">Display Account List</h2>
<lightning:layout>
    <article class="slds-card slds-m-bottom_medium">
     <div class="slds-media__body">
     <div>
    <lightning:layoutitem>
              <lightning:select aura:id="act" name="selectAccount" >
                  <option value="" label="--None--">
                  </option>
                  <aura:iteration items="{!v.Accounts}" var="item" >
                      <option value="{!item.Id}" label="{!item.name}" >
                          {!item.name}
                      </option>
                  </aura:iteration>
              </lightning:select>
    </lightning:layoutitem>
      </div>
      </div>
    </article>
</lightning:layout>
```

```
({
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var result =response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
            component.set("v.Accounts",result);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

```
public with sharing class AccountList {
  @Auraenabled
  public static List<Account> getAccounts()
  {
      return ([Select Id, Name from Account]);
  }
```

}

When I load this component (by using it in testLightning.app),
no account name appears in the dropdown.

Comment: You are not doing any validation in your lightning controller, try adding exception handling and debugging, this way you can narrow down the problem and add further details to your post so ohter can better assist you. Refer to [Error Handling Best Practices for Lightning and Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because of **{!item.name}**. Change it to:

> {!item.Name}

and that should work.

This is what is observed while retrieving the field names from the Apex controller. Even if you have the field names specified in the SOQL in lower case (specifically observed this on standard fields), say as below:

> select id, name from account

The returned response will have the result set with the first character capitalized as:

> Account:{**I**d=xyz, **N**ame=xyz}

The same is then passed to the JS controller function and that JS is case sensitive, it expects the values to be referred with the same case.

Comment: you might want to mention why your solution should work rather than just  mention what to change to make it work, and are you 100% sure this is the reason why the OP code is not working?

Comment: Good call, added observation in there. And yes, I did verify that cause of that not working.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code and verified that this solution is 100% the issue. Additionally there is another issue in the user's code. The lightning:select component requires a label attribute or it will throw an internal server error. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm

Comment: @gNerb That's interesting. I copied the same code, without realizing that label is required, and it worked perfectly fine. Wonder if it's related to release version?

Comment: That may be I checked and my bundle version shows it's using version 41 for the API.

Comment: It's even more interesting now. I am on 42! Tried downgrading, no issues reported.

Comment: @gNerb : It wasn't working for me either until I added label attribute to the lightning.select component.

Comment: @M.Anand if it worked for you, please select the check mark next to the question so that other people who have the same question know that this answer worked for you.

Comment: @gNerb Did you mean M. Anand? :)